# How can I access Google Fit data without logging in

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-fit, google-api-js-client

I have a web page I am working on, I am wanting to use gapi to access my steps for the day. I do not want to log in every time, I want the page to log in automatically in the background, oAuth2 is required I believe but I can not get any further.

Based on code I've found online and using React with Hooks, I added ts ignore because it could not resolve gapi.

The issue I am having is that I get Login Required error

I've tried using Axios and doing it by API_KEY only. My knowledge on API's is growing but I thought just to access the data an API key would be enough providing I had registered the key in the API tools.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
        const start = () => {
            // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
            // @ts-ignore
            gapi.client.init({
                'apiKey': '<API_KEY>',
                // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
                'clientId': '<CLIENT_ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            }).then(function() {
                // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
                // @ts-ignore
                return gapi.client.request({
                    'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/<MY_GMAIL_ADDRESS>/dataset:aggregate',
                    'method': 'POST',
                    'body': {
                        "aggregateBy": [{
                            "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
                            "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
                        }],
                        "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
                        "startTimeMillis": 1567983600000,
                        "endTimeMillis": 1568057160150
                    },
                })
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.result);
            }, function(reason) {
                console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
            });
        };

        // @ts-ignore
        gapi.load('client', start);
    }, []);
```

I just want to be able to return my steps in a JSON object preferably with Axios, if not using the gapi JS library using my React Application. Nothing fancy.

I appreciate this may not be possible but the docs and other questions on stack overflow just are not working for me and no one can answer me.